# Styles and Bindings in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, styles

For a better understanding of WPF bindings:

```
<Style x:Key="myButton" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter 
    Property="Content" 
    Value="{Binding 
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=My:Control}, 
             Path=Text}">
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Button Name="button1" Style="{StaticResource myButton}"></Button>
<Button Name="button2" Style="{StaticResource myButton}"></Button>
```

When I use this Style on multiple buttons, I assume the Style is only instantiated ones. What does it mean for the Binding? Do I have only one Binding (i.e. one Binding-Object) and button1 and button2 are referencing to this one Binding-object? If so, when and how is the Source of the Binding identified when button1 and button2 are used as part of different My:Control controls? By that I mean reference to the source-object not the value of the source? Can someone point me towards some specification where this is stated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I assume the Style is only instantiated ones*

Yes, here's proof of that using your code

[image]

*Do I have only one Binding (i.e. one Binding-Object) and button1 and button2 are referencing to this one Binding-object?*

Yes, since the style holds the binding and the objects are the same (literally) then the binding has to be the same.

[image]

*If so, when and how is the Source of the Binding identified when button1 and button2 are used as part of different My:Control controls?*

**When:** When the visual tree is rendered the bindings are evaluated by walking up to the control specified by `FindAncestor`

**How:** Now you're talking about implementation details. While I don't know exactly how `FindAncestor` works (one way to see is through .NET Reflector), it probably uses `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(...)`

**EDIT:**

the `BindingExpression` isn't tied to the `Binding` of the object, but you can easily get it like this.

[image]

As expected, both buttons have different `BindingExpression` but the same `Binding` object. The `BindingExpression` ties the `Target` with the `Source`. In this case, `ResolvedSource` is null as a result of using `RelativeSource` to find the property

[image]

Comment: I asked the same qestion to a friend. He explained that there is a difference between a BindingExpression and a Binding-object. What I specified in the Style is a BindingExpression. And since the Style is only instantiated once, the BindingExpression is probably as well. So both button reference the same BindingExpression. At some point during execution the BindingExpression is evaluated and a Binding-object is created. In this creation process the FindAncestor is evaluated based on the current position of the button in the tree. At the end each button has its own and different Binding-object.

Comment: In general this explanation fits your explanation, but with one minor detail. The distinction between Binding-object and BindingExpression-object.

Comment: Both buttons reference the same binding, but both button's won't have the same `BindingExpression` because `BindingExpression` contains the information about the `Target`.

Comment: Ah, ok. It seems I used the right terms but swapped their meaning.